# What is XMLNodeType - C#?

Tags: c#, xml

Could someone explain in layman terms what this actually does?

```
XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(workingDir + @"\ModulesList.xml");

            textReader.Read();

                if (textReader.Name == "Name")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    XmlNodeType nType = textReader.NodeType;
                }
                if (nType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(textReader.Value.ToString());
                }
```

I don't understand the purpose of XmlNodeType and NodeType on the textreader. Please could someone clear it up for it in like the simplest way :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `XmlReader` is like a forward-only cursor through an XML document. Aside from the fact that your code won't compile (you're declaring `nType` in one block and then using it in another), [`XmlReader.NodeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.nodetype.aspx) returns the current type of node the XML reader is looking at - an element, a text node, an attribute etc. [`XmlNodeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype.aspx) is the enum of possible values for `XmlReader.NodeType`.

Each time you call `Read`, the reader will move on to the next node - and what you want to *do* with that node will often depend on its type.

Personally I would steer clear of `XmlReader` *unless* you're trying to read a huge document which won't fit into memory. It's a much harder API to use properly than APIs which load a whole document into a tree, and let you navigate around that tree. LINQ to XML is a particularly nice API *if* you're in a situation where you can use it.

Answer (score 3):

I think [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype.aspx) can sum it up the best.

The short is `XmlNodeType` is an enum defining the type of Xml Node that you are currently reading in the XML via the `XmlReader`

Comment: I looked on MSDN but was looking for a dumbed down version of the explanation :P